# AVR - NRF24L01+ : Encrypt Data Transmission

Tags: avr, encryption

I have a pair of AVR's that communicate over the 2.4GHz link using NRF24l01+. The payload sent is 5 bytes long.

Right now the payload sent is in clear format so that anyone with enough knowledge and skill could theoretically build a device to intercept the data stream.

Can you please provide me with some recommendations on ways to encrypt this data stream considering it would be implemented on a 8 bit AVR (small code size) and would be done real time (so should be fast).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XXTEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XXTEA), [Keeloq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KeeLoq), [TEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) are suitable encryption algorithms for microcontrollers with small amount of RAM.

If the data are usually constant you will have to use a rolling code method to prevent replay attack.

Comment: Decided to go with XTEA with 1 byte random data inserted to randomize the encrypted output when using the same input data